# Delphi TDBGrid onDrawColumnCell Issue with first row

Tags: delphi, grid

I have written a procedure for OnDrawColumnCell for TDBGRID. When i leave the mouse over the first Row of Grid, the OnDrawColumnCell is called continuously and never stops. Is there a way to work over with this?

```
procedure TInvoicesUnpaidGrid.dbgDrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
const Rect:   TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; 
State:TGridDrawState);
begin
if (dc.DataSet.FieldValues['Overdue']=1) then
  dbg.Canvas.Font.Color:=clRed;
end;
```

Comment: There is nothing in the code you've posted that would cause that behavior. It's elsewhere in your code. Do you have anything in any other grid-related events? Anything in your mouse-related events?

Comment: there is no other event related with the Grid. It is indeed very strange and happens only with the first row.

Comment: As I said, there is nothing in the code you've posted that will cause that behavior. (I've got many CRUD applications that use TDBGrid to display data, with various row colors to indicate status, and use very similar code in all of them without issue.) Do you have *any* mouse-related events (not just for the DBGrid, but *any* mouse related)?

Comment: Have a look at the Options property group of your TDBGrid.  Is dgEditing set to True?  If so, does setting it to false stop the behaviour you're seeing?  In my test project, a breakpoint inset the CustomDrawCell event breaks continually if dgEditing = True.

Comment: How do you observe this behavior ? Don't you have set a breakpoint on that event code and covering your grid by the IDE when debugging ? That might cause the grid to be repainted over and over again.

Comment: About the breakpoint, it doesn't cause the repaint as this happens only to the first row. As MartynA told me, I made tests with dgediting. Finally i found that the problem is when dgTitleClick is TRUE. It is really very strange